# How to detect fundamental frequency with comb filter?

Tags: java, filter, fft, audio-processing

I have to use comb filter to detect dominant frequency of sound file, or frequencies if it's sounds sequence. I searched for any implementation or explanation of this problem, but unfortunately could not find anything.

What I've got so far: I'm loading a wav file to my java application, then convert it to frequency domain with FFT.

What should I do next? And how to implement this comb filter for frequency detection? I'm not asking for a code, just tell me how should I approach this problem. I'm not allowed to use external libraries. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the "Harmonic Product Spectrum" algorithm or method.

You can either use a fixed comb template and match it against a varying rescaling of your FFT spectrums width for best match, or you can match a fixed spectrum against a range of combs of varying frequency spaced "teeth".  Interpolation or filtering can be used for rescaling (a form of resampling).  Successive approximation can improve the best filter match, and thus improve the frequency estimation.  The best match should be a good estimate of the fundamental pitch or periodicity frequency, or possibly a sub-harmonic.

Answer (score 0):

In my frequency detection method I generated N comb filters with following scheme:

```
filter1 -> 10-1010-1 ...
filter2 -> 100-100100-100...
filter3 -> 1000-10001000-1000...
filterN -> 1N0-1N0
```

My steps after calculating fft:

1. Get magnitude part from fft result
2. Calculate in a loop sum of each comb filter with magnitude of fft result
3. If current sum is greater than previous one, set sumMax as current sum, and calculate frequency by multipling space between each comb and quotient of sample rate and window size

This approach is not perfect but works for frequency detection of basic sounds.